# set default g++ on CentOS?

Tags: centos, version, defaults, g++

I'm trying to set the default g++ to 4.7.2 which I'm told by my host is installed (I'm also told that c++11 is also installed); however, neither of us know how to set the default g++ to 4.7.2 because `g++ --version` gives

```
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I tried these `sudo` commands here, but I just found out that they don't work because CentOS uses `yum`.

How can I set the default g++ to 4.7.2 (if it's even installed) on CentOS 5.9?

Comment: The stock version of gcc in the CentOS repos is 4.1.2 (with the option of 4.4). Have you tried [this answer to "Install gcc 4.7 on CentOS"](http://superuser.com/a/542091/191578)?

Comment: @ReedKraft-Murphy sorry for deleting that last post out from under you.  I saw your answer too late.  when i do the `yum --enablerepo=testing-devtools-6 install devtoolset-1.0-gcc` line, it gives `Error getting repository data for testing-devtools-6, repository not found`.  Thank you for helping!  (I'm going to ask this in a formal question)

Comment: No worries. Since you're on CentOS 5.x, rather than 6.x, I'm guessing you'll need to say `yum --enablerepo=testing-devtools-5 ...` rather than `testing-devtools-6`, but I'll happily take this to a formal question :)

Comment: @ReedKraft-Murphy thank you reed!  i've moved it here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/how-to-install-g4-7-2-c11-on-centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the CXX environment variable. For example, `export CXX="/usr/bin/g++-4.7"` . And CC is the one that controls the C compiler.

Comment: Thank-you for looking!  I tried that, and I'm still getting the same result for `--version`.  I tried executing `/usr/bin/g++-4.7`.  Does that mean it's not even installed?

Comment: Well, the path in my answer was only an example. If you don't know if/where the newer g++ is, it's gonna be more difficult.

Comment: in centOS 6 you will find it here:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcc